# How to script the commands in the menu of DigitalMicrograph?

Tags: dm-script

Is it possible to write a script that can also execute the commands which are already in the DigitalMicrograph application menu?

Comment: what is DigitalMicrograph? Do you mean [this](http://www.gatan.com/products/tem-analysis/gatan-microscopy-suite-software#resources)? See [this](http://www.gatan.com/resources/scripts)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter -_-

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the command you are seeking is called `ChooseMenuItem`. It takes three string parameters as input, the full signature is

> Boolean ChooseMenuItem( String *menu_name*, String *sub_menu_name*, String *menu_item_name* )

And example (assuming an image is open) would be

```
GetFrontImage().SelectImage()
ChooseMenuItem( "Analysis", "Statistics", "Sum" )
```

Note the use of `SelectImage` in the example because the menu command is only available if an image window is selected!

You may also want to use things below to catch if a given menu item is not accessible. The command `ChooseMenuItem` returns a Boolean *true* on success and a *false* on failure.

```
string menu = "Analysis"
string submenu = "Special"
string item = "Variance"
If ( !ChooseMenuItem( menu, submenu, item ) )
    Throw( "The menu-command " + menu + " / "+ submenu + " / " + item + "  was not found!" )
```